# RTL8188FU driver for Linux kernel 4.15.x ~ 5.11.x

Tags: drivers

Is this safe driver for ubuntu 20.4.2?
https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Safe' may have several meanings. Is it safe from spyware, malware, adware, ransomeware, etc.? I believe it is. First, it is open source software meaning that we can all read every word of the code and spot anything suspicious. I have read much of it and I see nothing at all harmful or not essential as a wireless driver.

Second, this driver has been downloaded many times, often recommended by me, and I never heard any complaints.

'Safe' might mean, does it compile correctly and drive my device as expected? I know that it compiles on my 5.11 kernel version with a few possibly harmless warnings. I strongly suspect that it also will compile on the mentioned kernels, that is, 4.15 through 5.11.

I haven't the device so I can't tell you if it works properly. Again, I am unaware of any complaints.

Please try it and report back. It can be installed, following the README, in just a few minutes. If it does *not* work properly, it can be removed in less.

Comment: Thanks for answering , It works properly and I read the code but I need someone expert verify it.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour